# How to find where an action is triggered?

Tags: actions

As far as I understand about the action hook, `add_action` is used to add callback functions to an **exsiting** action hook, which means, to make lines like

```
add_action('some_action_hook',function(){ // some function})
```

work, you need to have a line that says do_action `some_action_hook` somewhere in your code. Is this understanding right?

I come across an action hook that I couldn't find where it is triggered: it is woocommerce's `woocommerce_thankyou_bacs`. I've done a thorough text search inside my website root folder for `woocommerce_thankyou_bacs`, the only line coming up is

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou_bacs', array( $this, 'thankyou_page' ) );
```

in `\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\gateways\bacs\class-wc-gateway-bacs.php`.
I've also done a regex search for `thankyou.*bacs`, the result is same. I also search this action hook online and in Woocommerce's documentation, but didn't get much useful informations.
This itself is trivial, but I'd like to know:

1. Is the understanding that where there is a `do_action`, there must be a corresponding `add_action` correct, or at least generally correct?
2. If 1) is correct, what is the solid way to find where `do_action` is for a certain action hook?

Comment: the action name can be assembled using variables, it doesn't have to be a static string, the WooCommerce documentation is the most appropriate place to look for the answer here. Also, you can add a function to an action that never gets called, and you can fire an action that is never hooked into. `add_action( 'qjfberbierb fi', ...` is still perfectly valid even though I mashed my keyboard to get the action name and it will never be ran.

Comment: Also, WooCommerce and other 3rd party plugin dev support questions are off topic here, this stack isn't a place to get help with WooCommerce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WooCommerce (my version v6.1.1) there is a file called `/woocommerce/templates/checkout/thankyou.php` and in `line 79` you have trigger with dynamic payment method name so there is a place when each payment method do their magic

```
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou_' . $order->get_payment_method(), $order->get_id() ); ?>
```

And answering your questions:

1. The opposite. Where is `add_action` there is a corresponding `do_action` but i can be named dynamically just like we see it example above
2. There is no 100% way to find each `do_action` because all hook names depends on creativity of developer. So i can be hard to find at first glance just like example above